# What happens to the Ubuntu SDK spin of QtCreator now that Unity8 has dissolved?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, qt, ubuntu-sdk, qt-creator, canonical

What happens to the Ubuntu SDK spin of QtCreator now that Unity8 has dissolved?

Is it going to continue development? Are its plugins still useful to Canonical such as for say, snap packaging? Are Developers now switching over to something gtk based?